# Why does my Python socket client stop sending data randomly?

Tags: python, python-3.x, sockets

Im writing a python program that makes a screenshot and then sends it over TCP, at least its what i tried. I mean it worked, but only when i was sending it from the server to the client, but not other way round.

**The program just hangs, and never continues to load further.**

So my issue:
I already tried out to send the screenshots (like every millisecond) from the server to the client, which worked, but now my plan is to send it from the client to the server and this doesnt work.
It does not throw an error, it just stops sending and the last command that is executed is
`size = len(img_bytes)`. Code:

```
#!/usr/bin/env python3

import socket
import pyautogui
import cv2
import numpy as np

def main():
    host = '127.0.0.1'
    port = 80

    client_socket = socket.socket(socket.AF_INET, socket.SOCK_STREAM)
    client_socket.connect((host, port))

    print('Connected to the server...')
    
    while True:
        try:
            screenshot = pyautogui.screenshot()
            frame = np.array(screenshot)
            _, img_encoded = cv2.imencode('.png', frame)
            img_bytes = img_encoded.tobytes()

            size = len(img_bytes)
            client_socket.sendall(size.to_bytes(4, 'big'))

            client_socket.sendall(img_bytes)
            print("Sending screenshot")
        except Exception as e:
            print('Error', e)
            break

    client_socket.close()

if __name__ == '__main__':
    main()
```

And my test server:

```
#!/usr/bin/env python3 

import socket
import time 

server_socket = socket.socket(socket.AF_INET, socket.SOCK_STREAM)
host = "0.0.0.0"
port = 80

server_socket.bind((host, port))
server_socket.listen(1)


while True:
    client_socket, client_address = server_socket.accept()
```

The same code and program, just that the server now sends these screenshots

```
#!/usr/bin/env python3

import socket
import pyautogui
import cv2
import numpy as np

def main():
    host = '0.0.0.0'
    port = 12345

    server_socket = socket.socket(socket.AF_INET, socket.SOCK_STREAM)
    server_socket.bind((host, port))
    
    server_socket.listen(1)

    print('Server is up and running...')

    client_socket, addr = server_socket.accept()
    
    print('Connected to:', addr)
    
    while True:
        try:
            screenshot = pyautogui.screenshot()
            frame = np.array(screenshot)
            _, img_encoded = cv2.imencode('.png', frame)
            img_bytes = img_encoded.tobytes()

            size = len(img_bytes)
            client_socket.sendall(size.to_bytes(4, 'big'))

            client_socket.sendall(img_bytes)
            print("Sending screenshot")
        except Exception as e:
            print('Error', e)
            break

    client_socket.close()
    server_socket.close()

if __name__ == '__main__':
    main()
```

I tried e.g. sending any strings from the client and this isnt limited, which worked and i know that its not throwing an error. It stops when "trying to?" execute line `client_socket.sendall(size.to_bytes(4, 'big'))`
I tried adding a timer of one second (didn't work), i also checked if it hangs when it executes size.to_bytes(...), but it just hangs when its trying to send the data.

Comment: Are you sure the last call isn't `sendall`? It could be a problem with `recv`. If the other side stops receiving, the stream could fill and `sendall` would hang. I don't see that code here, but its worth seeing if that is where the problem is.

Comment: Thanks for your help already. No way, you were right. It didn't send it because i didn't receive anything. And i didn't know that. Now i feel like an idiot. Im wondering how the client knows that the message was not received by the server

Comment: That's part of TCP. Data is sent with a sequence number and the receiving stack updates that number, letting the sender know that a chunk was received. If it doesn't get an update, it may retry. Eventually it will get bored and error out on the sender side, but that takes a long time.